# Android toolbar abstract behaviour

Tags: android, toolbar, abstraction

I want to make a toolbar with a simple about button.
I have tons of activities but I don't want to implement the same onOptionItemSelected and onCreateOptionsMenu as many times as many activities I have. Is there any way to give this toolbar some kind of abstraction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reusing the same toolbar across your activities, you can create a BaseActivity which handles inflation of your menu and then you can extend this BaseActivity for all other Activities.

Implement `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionItemSelected` in the BaseActivity. In that case, you don't need to implement these methods individually in all activities.

Comment: Smart and obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)